# Transformation of table in R

Tags: r, tablerow, tablecolumn

I have a table like described below:

| in_key | in_id | ro_id | data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 42 | Text | 1 | 1 |
| 42 | Text | 2 | 1 |
| 43 | Text | 3 | 0 |
| 43 | Text | 4 | 0 |
| 44 | Text | 5 | 0 |
| 44 | Text | 6 | 0 |

I need to transform this table in format:

| ro_1 | ro_2 | ro_3 | in_key | in_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Value | Value | Value | 42 | Text |

Where values of **ro_1, ro_2,** etc are taken from corresponding values in data column and indexes in column names such as **_1, _2,** are taken from values in **ro_id** column. The **in_key** value should correspond same as table 1.

How to approach to this in R? In SPSS this transformation can be done easily but I would like to see an R solution for this.

Kinds

Comment: `pivot_wider(dat, c(in_key, in_id), names_from = "ro_id", values_from = "data", names_prefix = "ro_")`

Comment: `out <- reshape2::dcast(in_key + in_id ~ ro_id, data = dat, value.var = "data"); names(out)[-(1:2)] <- paste0("ro_", names(out)[-(1:2)]); out`

Comment: Perfect @r2evans thank you. both solutions work, but I prefer first since second generated an error and needed me to remove labels from SPSS table